# Erro ao criar um arquivo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Por algum motivo não consegue criar um arquivo.

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
OutputStream outputStream;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

            File dir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            dir.mkdir();
            File file = new File(dir,System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Salve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

E o xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mario"></ImageView>
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/save"
        android:text = "save"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

E no manifest eu coloquei as permissões de ler e gravar

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

e também dei as permissões dentro do android.

Já tentei varias formas diferentes e ele continua não funcionando, se eu verifico se o diretório e/ou o arquivo já existem, ele indica que não existe, e ao tentar criar o arquivo ele retorna o erro `No such file or directory`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser, ou de que eu to fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar, é um padrão que uso ao criar arquivos;

```
   usar File.separator ex:File dir = new File(caminhoPastaTemp + File.separator + uuid);


   if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    //arquivoParametro é o file vc vai pegar os bytes para salvar;
   //Util.removerAcentos é um método meu que retira os acentos
    byte[] arquivo = arquivoParametro.getBytes();
   String nomeArquivo = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Util.removerAcentos(arquivoParametro.getOriginalFilename())

    FileOutputStream file  = null;
    try{
        file = new FileOutputStream(nomeArquivo);
        file.write(arquivo);   //importante
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }catch(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }finally{
        if(file!=null){
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: tentei aqui e ao fazer ele diz que não pode alterar pois só esta em modo Read, mudei o dir para `File dir = getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` e deu certo. vlw

Comment: Depois da uma lida na  utilização de try catch e finally vai melhorar a escrita do seu código. 


  [1]: https://www.devmedia.com.br/blocos-try-catch/7339

Comment: eu to ligado que ta mal escrito, tava fazendo uns teste só kkkk